# Python with VS2015: Projects

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

Hi I'm a beginner with Python. I have installed Python Tools for VS2015.
I have created a project called Learning_Python, so VS2015 has created a `Learning_Python.sln` file, a `Learning_Python` folder and a `Learning_Python.py` file inside that folder.

In the `Learning_Python` file i have a script with whatever instructions.
In solution explorer, i have right clicked on "Learning_Python" and added an existing file, called `requestwebpage.py`, with some Python script.

now when i click on the green arrow "start" in VS2015, the script `Learning_Python.py` will execute, but NOT the script in `requestwebpage.py`

why is it so ? basically, i don't want to create a new project everytime for every possible .py file ...

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a partial answer:

i right-click on `requestwebpage.py` in solution explorer and i could set it up as the startup file. alternatively, right clicking in solution explorer on Learning_Python solution, i can choose "properties" and modify the startup file in the new window...

That solves my problem, i believe.